# How to find the area of a semicircle inside of another semicircle?

Tags: geometry, circles, area

I am stumped on how to solve this problem. I've tried to look up the problem, but to no avail. What I need to know is how can I find the area of a semicircle cut off by the curve of another semicircle?

I have an example image [here](https://i.imgur.com/BZzwDyD.png)

The radius of the larger semicircle is 1 inch, while the radius of the smaller semicircle is 0.5 inches. I can easily understand how to find the area of the larger semicircle, but I cannot find the area of the smaller one, as it is not a true semicircle (the bottom is cut off by the curve of the larger semicircle.)

Any help or an answer would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with integration?

Comment: No, I am a high school freshman in geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area of intersection between two circles is:

[image]

where $d$ is the distance between two centers, R and r are the two radii. In your case: $R = 1 in$, $r=0.5 in$ and $d=R=1 in$.

[source] http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: Wouldn't _d_ = 1? Isn't the distance between the two centers 1, because the center of the small circle is right on the edge of the large circle, and the large circle has a radius of 1?

Comment: yeah, that's right!

Comment: I am trying your equation, but when I get to the inverse cosines, I get an error when entering it in the calculator!

I simplified the first parenthesis to (2.25/1) which is just 2.25.

However, cos-1(2.25) gets me an error in the calculator! What can I do?

Comment: Whoops, I messed up. Nevermind! I did d^2 + r^2 + R^2, instead of d^2 + r^2 - R^2.

Comment: The first parenthesis is $\frac{r}{2d} = 0.25$ , you might have not seen the minus sign.

Comment: I tried and got 47.3515234071 in^2. I definitely feel like I did something wrong, as there is no way a circle with _r_ = .5 can get me that. Is your equation correct or did I do something wrong? I used degrees instead of radians for inverse cosine, maybe that was it...?

Comment: Are you sure that your calculations were in radian not in degrees?

Comment: Nevermind, I used radians and got ~0.35. I checked with somebody using some integrals and stuff I don't know, and they got the same answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

N.B. $\operatorname{cs}(ACD)$ is the circle segment defined by the rays, $AC$ and $AD$.

In the piture below, we have that $$\operatorname{cs}(ACD)+\operatorname{cs}(BCD)$$ contains the part were looking for. However we have overcounted. Can you see by how much we overcounted (i.e. what we now need to substract)?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are saying here. I'm pretty sure only ACD contains the part I am looking for, and I do not know how to find it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: $\operatorname{cs}(ACD)$ is a slice of the big circle. What do I get when I consider that slice whithout $\triangle ACD$...?

Comment: @D.B. Also note that I describe a very general case. In your case $B$ lies on the great circle I believe. This method then still holds.